# PHP - Preg_match escaping fix?

Tags: php, preg-replace

**FIXED:** Aha, just replace

> *.?

for

> .*?

and it worked ;p

---

I made a function but doesn't seem to work, I think it's because escaping is wrong, can you guys check it?

```
function clearPage($content, $id) {
$arr = array(
            "@(*.?)<div id=\"$id\">(*.?)<\/div>(*.?)@i" => "<div id=\"$id\">$2</div>"
            );

    return preg_replace(array_keys($arr), array_values($arr), $content);


}
```

Please ignore its purpose and focus on the array?

Comment: I noticed that you're escaping in `(*.?)<\/div>` but not at the end in `$2</div>`.

Comment: Have you tried making them both as `</\div>` or `</div>`?

Comment: It works without escaping in the values.

Comment: Noup, but replaced *.? for .*? and worked, LOL

Comment: Great, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure to not have nested divs, you can use this syntax:

```
'@(.*?)<div id="' . $id. '">(.*?)</div>(.*?)@is'
```

Note the use of single quotes to avoid to escape double quote, and the use of the s modifier to allow the dot to match newlines. You don't have to escape slashes since you don't use slashes as delimiters.

Notice: in your case using regex is a very bad way, especially since you have an id which can be used easily with DOMDocument.

Comment: @AfonsoMatos: a dyslexia problem then.